# How to make a flexbox shrink as the page gets smaller

Tags: css

I want to make my container flexbox shrink as the page gets smaller

**HTML**

```
// this is Vue.js
<div class="background-image-container">
 <div class="background-image" style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + bgImageUrl + ')' }">
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background-image-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.background-image {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 180px;
  max-height: 350px;
  height: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

**EDIT**

changed the HTML so it's readable

**EDIT 2**

fixed the CSS

Comment: Shrink in what way? Reduce height/width/both?

Comment: just the height. so basically when the page gets smaller the height will too but never going less than 180px (and exceeding 350 if the page is bigger). I can't help but feel I'm doing it wrong though?

Comment: You can try playing with vh instead of px for the height value, this is calculated based on the viewport height, so it will automatically reduce as your screen height reduces. You may have to play around with the value to get it looking right (you can also set a max- and min-height so it never gets too large/small).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of vw and vh for width and height. Here's the code snippet for it:

```css
.background-image-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 180px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 350px;
  
}

.background-image {
background-image: url("http://www.xsjjys.com/data/out/211/WHDQ-513480478.jpg");
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image-container">
 <div class="background-image">
 </div>
</div>
```